# Three stage amplifier with third transistor connected to emitter of second

Tags: transistors, amplifier

[image: Amplifier]

[image: Solved]

My question is that for voltage gain, is it correct if I take voltage gain of each transistor and then multiplying, to get gain of whole circuit?

Comment: It would be correct if each stage saw infinite impedance at the next stage input.

Comment: Rg, Re3 seems to be too much. Re2 seems too low. Global Av is not the product of the three "internal" local Avi ...

Comment: Show how you get the values of components. TR2 is a follower, so its voltage "gain" should be < 1.

Comment: What's the purpose of RC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The used expressions for the 2nd stage is wrong. The gain must be positive and below unity (emitter follower).
- The product of the individual gains for the 3 stages - when correctly calculated - gives the so-called "loop gain" (A_loop). This is the gain of the complete feedback loop when it is opened at a "suitable" node.

What means "suitable"? One should find a node where a small output resistance is conncted at a high input resistance so that opening at this node will not drastically change the loading conditions. Such a node could be the emitter of Q2.

So you would start the analysis of the three stages with a test voltage at the base of Q3 (open the loop at this point before!). The collector of Q3 is connected via Rf to the emitter of Q1 (common base principle)....output of the 3-stage chain now is the emitter of Q3.

When you have the loop gain A_loop you can find the gain of the closed-loop Acl using the well-known formula

**Acl=Aol/(1+A_loop)** with Aol being the gain without negative feedback.

For calculating Aol the feedback loop must be opened and the path inluding Rf must be considered as an additional load at the collector of Q3.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve it now.

Answer (score 0):

> *My question is that for voltage gain, is it correct if I take voltage
> gain of each transistor and then multiplying, to get gain of whole
> circuit?*

That would be incorrect because you have AC negative feedback from TR3's collector to TR1's emitter via \$R_F\$ and the series capacitor. These components will define the voltage gain of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit does not function correctly.
Here is what happens ... Q1 is deeply saturated, so "no" voltage gain.

[image]

Here is the AC Analysis of the circuit ...

[image]

After some changes, this should be :

[image]

Which lead to AC Analysis much better

[image]